# Scrolling storyboard elements that are off screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard

I am using Xcode 5 and ios 7. I have a view which has size 320x1200 which contains various static elements such as buttons,images etc.

1. I created View controller,
2. I added Scroll View of same size to this View Controller
3. I Added View to Scroll View and changed the size of the view to 320x1200
4. I selected main/root View Controller and used EDITOR -> Resolve Auto Layout..-> Add Missing Constraints (to enable scroll).

Now I can scroll but I still cannot see the off screen content. Is there any way to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Resize the Scroll View to the root view's size (e.g. 320x480 on iPhone 4) and set its **content size** to 320x1200 instead.

Comment: You mentioned the auto layout constraints. Fix the width/height constraints that might be forcing the view size to 320x1200 and change them to 320x480 or 320x568 depending on the device.